# Finding objects which contains at least one element from subset using RavenDB and LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ravendb

I have simple type `Question`:

```
public class Question
{
    public Question(string id)
    {
        Id = id;
        Tags = new List<string>();
    }

    public string Id { get; private set; }
    public IList<string> Tags { get; set; }            
}
```

I have defined sample collection of such questions:

```
var q1 = new Question("q1") { Tags = new List<string>() {"a"} };
var q2 = new Question("q2") { Tags = new List<string>() {"b"} };
var q3 = new Question("q3") { Tags = new List<string>() {"a", "b", "c"} };
var q4 = new Question("q4") { Tags = new List<string>() {"a", "b"} };
var q5 = new Question("q5") { Tags = new List<string>() {"z"} };
var q6 = new Question("q6");
var questions = new List<Question>() {q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6};
```

Now I need to find **all questions, which contains at least one tag, from given subset**. Subset is defined below:

```
string[] tags = new[] {"a", "b"};
```

I expect **q1**, **q2**, **q3** and **q4** to be returned. The query which I use to get desired result is:

```
var questions = DocumentSession.Query<Question>().AsQueryable();
questions = GetQuestionsToContainingAtLeastOneTagFromSubset(questions, tags)
// some other query restrictions
var result = questions.ToList(); // (**)
```

The function which suppose to impose restrictions on my collection is following:

```
private IQueryable<Question> GetQuestionsToContainingAtLeastOneTagFromSubset(IQueryable<Question> questions, IEnumerable<string> tags)
{
    var result = new List<Question>();
    foreach (var tag in tags)
    {
        var currentTag = tag;
        var resultForTag = questions.Where(x => x.Tags.Any(xTag => xTag == currentTag));
        result = result.Concat(resultForTag).ToList();
     }
     return result.GroupBy(x => x.Id).Select(grp => grp.First()).AsQueryable();
}
```

I think this is highly inefficient. I'd like to avoid using `.ToList()` inside the provided function. As I understand this `.ToList()` expressions queries the RavenDB and returns me partial results (BTW: am I right ?). This is not efficient. I only want to impose restrictions in the provided function, and execute the query after all of the restrictions are imposed. The `(**)` place is good for me to sent the batch to RavenDB retrieve query result.

How to improve that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query lucene to get the questions with tags that match yor tag aray array something like this:

```
string[] tags = new[] { "a", "b" };
string queryRange = "(" + string.Join(" OR ", tags) + ")";

var res = session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<Question>()
               .Where("Tags:" + queryRange).ToList();
```

Note that this queries the entire indexed questions, not a subset. But I think you can append - I GUESS - to the query string expression.
See Lucene docs for more about these kind of queries:
http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_0/queryparsersyntax.html

Comment: Thanks for that tip. I've changed the data in my question just because I want to show You that this is not working as expected. The Lucene query in debugger transforms to {Tags: a OR b},  and for some reason it returns only q1, q3 and q4. It suppose to return also q2, but it doesn't. Besides, I'd like to avoid LuceneQuery in this particular example.

Comment: Try this queryRange:
string queryRange = "(" + string.Join(" OR ", tags) + ")"; I updated my answer. As for not using an explicit lucene query...I do prefer linq queries, but if lucene provides and ravendb exposes, why not use it? :) it's quite simple

Comment: Thanks, it works now. It seems to be quite simple indeed. I wanted to avoid Lucene queries, because I thought about building successive restrictions. While I have IQueryable collection with some restrictions already added, I cannot further apply Lucene restrictions. Access to building Lucene queries is avaliable from Raven.Client.IDocumentSession and I'd love to apply restristions which do the same, but using IQueryable with Linq.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
 var q1 = new Question("q1") { Tags = new List<string>() {"aa", "bb"} };
 var q2 = new Question("q2") { Tags = new List<string>() {"aa"} };
 var q3 = new Question("q3") { Tags = new List<string>() {"aa", "bb", "cc"} };
 var q4 = new Question("q4");
 var questions = new List<Question>() {q1, q2, q3, q4};
 string[] tags = new[] { "bb", "cc" };

 var res = (from p in questions where 
           (from q in tags where p.Tags.Contains(q) == true select p).ToArray().Count() >= 1 
            select p).Distinct(); 
 //If you want more speed you can try to add .AsParallel() after .Distinct()
```

Comment: Your first where clause can be simplified to (from q in tags where p.Tags.Contains(q) select p).Any() select p), but anyway, RavenDB throws an exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot understand how to translate value....tags.Where(q => p.Tags.Contains(q)).Select(q => p)

Comment: Using linq-to-objects this works, but Raven driver has some issues processing that and throws the same type of exception.

Comment: Please note that RavenDB doesn't support (at least yet) a few important queryable operations (.Selectmany for example), so although the api is exposed via some kind of queryablem, expect not to work...IQueryable<> has so much operations defined in the contract that is almost impossible to implement them such a way that it should work with an extenral source (NOT clr objects).

Comment: I know, I'm just asking because maybe it can be done in any better way I did it, and I don't know how at this moment. If not, I'll just use Lucene.