# Query objects containing at least one element from a subset with RavenDB and LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ravendb

I have a similar issue addressed in this thread : [Finding objects which contains at least one element from subset using RavenDB and LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137547/finding-objects-which-contains-at-least-one-element-from-subset-using-ravendb-an), but the answer is not clear to me.

```
string[] Categories = new[] {"A", "B"};

foreach (var cat in Categories)
{
   var currentTag = cat;
   products = products.Where(p => p.Categories.Any(c =>c.Id == currentTag));
}
```

When debugging "Products", the result is an "AND" and not an "**OR**" between each where statement (e.g. ...where category=A AND category=B. How can you make the same, just with an OR operator?

I mean, give me all products, that at least have category A **OR** B.

Best
Nima

Comment: Any is an Or, All is an And.

Comment: Tim : Thanks, just corrected the sample.

Comment: "All" seems not to be supported in Raven - and "Any" is giving the "AND". Something I am missing out?

Comment: @Nima It is not that Any is giving the AND, it is fact you are composing the query in a loop in a way that results in and behavior.

Comment: @Euphoric thank you very much - works like charm!! Was struggling with this for some time now - really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `In` operator.

```
string[] cats = new[] {"A", "B"};

var products = session.Query<Products>().Where(p => p.Categories.Any(c =>c.Id.In(cats)));
```